# Quarkus client unable to connect to remote Kafka in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, quarkus

Really hope you could help me out! Thank you in advance!

I installed Kafka via helm chart with the service is "ClusterIP" in namespace "ns1" in a kubernetes cluster.

Then, i create a new namespace "ns2" and install kafka client to test it, everything works perfectly:

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka.ns1:9092 --topic test
```

Then, I install another pod (Quarkus producer for Kafka) in a different namespace "ns2" to connect to that kafka service with this configuration in "application.properties"

```
kafka.bootstrap.servers='kafka.ns1':9092
```

It shows this error (really don't understand why localhost is showing here:

```
2023-07-03 17:40:54,863 INFO  [io.sma.rea.mes.kafka] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-0) SRMSG18258: Kafka producer kafka-producer-topic, connected to Kafka brokers ''kafka.ns1':9092', is configured to write records to 'topic'
2023-07-03 17:40:54,945 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | kafka-producer-topic) [Producer clientId=kafka-producer-opcua] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-07-03 17:40:54,946 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | kafka-producer-topic) [Producer clientId=kafka-producer-topic] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-07-03 17:40:55,049 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | kafka-producer-topic) [Producer clientId=kafka-producer-opcua] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-07-03 17:40:55,071 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | kafka-producer-topic) [Producer clientId=kafka-producer-topic] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: First, I would remove the quotes around the host name. Kafka considers them and cannot connect. Then, I believe you need the full-service name and not only the "service.namespace".